# Function that compares 1st and last element, 2nd and 2nd last element, and so on

Tags: python, list

I want to write a function that compares the first element of this list with the last element of this list, the second element of this list with the second last element of this list, and so on. If the compared elements are the same, I want to add the element to a new list. Finally, I'd like to print this new list.

For example,

```
>>> f([1,5,7,7,8,1])
[1,7]
>>> f([3,1,4,1,5]
[1,4]
>>> f([2,3,5,7,1,3,5])
[3,7]
```

I was thinking to take the first (i) and last (k) element, compare them, then raise i but lower k, then repeat the process. When i and k 'overlap', stop, and print the list. I've tried to visualise my thoughts in the following code:

```
def f(x): 
    newlist=[]
    k=len(x)-1
    i=0
    for j in x:
        if x[i]==x[k]:
            if i<k:
                newlist.append(x[i])
        i=i+1
        k=k-1
    print(newlist)
```

Please let me know if there are any errors in my code, or if there is a more suitable way to address the problem.

As I am new to Python, I am not very good with understanding complicated terminology/features of Python. As such, it would be encouraged if you took this into account in your answer.

Comment: Iterating over a sequence yields elements, not indexes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I see! I've edited my code to fix this.

Comment: why your second example returns [4] as well, but the third example does not return [7]? (in both cases they are the elements "at the center" of the list)

Comment: @FLab fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a conditional list comprehension with `enumerate`, comparing the element `x` at index `i` to the element at index `-1-i` (`-1` being the last index of the list):

```
>>> lst = [1,5,7,7,8,1]
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(lst[:(len(lst)+1)//2]) if lst[-1-i] == x]
[1, 7]
>>> lst = [3,1,4,1,5]
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(lst[:(len(lst)+1)//2]) if lst[-1-i] == x]
[1, 4]
```

Or, as already suggested in other answers, use `zip`. However, it is enough to slice the first argument; the second one can just be the `reversed` list, as `zip` will stop once one of the argument lists is finished, making the code a bit shorter.

```
>>> [x for x, y in zip(lst[:(len(lst)+1)//2], reversed(lst)) if x == y]
```

In both approaches, `(len(lst)+1)//2` is equivalent to `int(math.ceil(len(lst)/2))`.

Comment: fails for `[3, 1, 4, 1, 5]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yup, off-by-one for odd-numbered lists. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like for even length of list:

```
>>> r=[l[i] for i in range(len(l)/2) if l[i]==l[-(i+1)]]
>>> r
[3]
>>> l=[1,5,7,7,8,1]
>>> r=[l[i] for i in range(len(l)/2) if l[i]==l[-(i+1)]]
>>> r
[1, 7]
```

And for odd length of list :

```
>>> l=[3,1,4,1,5]
>>> r=[l[i] for i in range(len(l)/2+1) if l[i]==l[-(i+1)]]
>>> r
[1, 4]
```

so you can create a function :

```
def myfunc(mylist):
     if (len(mylist) % 2 == 0):
            return [l[i] for i in range(len(l)/2) if l[i]==l[-(i+1)]]
     else:
            return [l[i] for i in range(len(l)/2+1) if l[i]==l[-(i+1)]]
```

and use it this way :

```
>>> l=[1,5,7,7,8,1]
>>> myfunc(l)
[1, 7]
>>> l=[3,1,4,1,5]
>>> myfunc(l)
[1, 4]
```

Comment: I imagine OP would want one solution that solves all problems.

Comment: Yes sure I have completed my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which leverages from [**`zip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def compare(lst):
    size = len(lst) // 2
    return [y for x, y in zip_longest(lst[:size], lst[-1:size-1:-1], fillvalue=None) if x == y or x is None]

print(compare([1, 5, 7, 7, 8, 1]))      # [1, 7]
print(compare([3, 1, 4, 1, 5]))         # [1, 4]
print(compare([2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5]))   # [3, 7]
```

---

**On `zip_longest`**:

Normally, `zip` stops `zip`ping when one of its iterators run out. `zip_longest` does not have that limitation and it simply keeps on `zip`ping by adding *dummy* values.

Example:

```
list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a']))                         # [(1, 'a')]
list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3], ['a'], fillvalue='z'))  # [(1, 'a'), (2, 'z'), (3, 'z')]
```

Comment: Could you explain what fillvalue and zip_longest do? I am not familiar with itertools.

Comment: @Jazzachi Added a link to the documentation and an example. It is really easy to understand.

Comment: No need for `zip_longest` with `size = (len(lst) + 1) // 2` and `zip(lst[:size], lst[-1:size-2:-1])`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is zip over the first half and the second half reversed and use list comprehensions to build a list of the same ones:

```
[element_1 for element_1, element_2 in zip(l[:len(l)//2], reversed(l[(len(l)+1)//2:])) if element_1 == element_2]
```

What happens is that you take the first half and iterate over those as element_1, the second half reversed as element_2 and then only add them if they are the same:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4]
l[:len(l)//2] == [1, 2, 3]
reversed(l[(len(l)+1)//2:])) == [4, 2, 3]
1 != 4, 2 == 2, 3 == 3, result == [2, 3]
```

If you also want to include the middle element in the case of an odd list, we can just extend our lists to both include the middle element, which will always evaluate as the same:

```
[element_1 for element_1, element_2 in zip(l[:(len(l) + 1)//2], reversed(l[len(l)//2:])) if element_1 == element_2]

l = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
l[:len(l)//2] == [3, 1, 4]
reversed(l[(len(l)+1)//2:])) == [5, 1, 4]
3 != 5, 1 == 1, 4 == 4, result == [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
[el1 for (el1, el2) in zip(L[:len(L)//2+1], L[len(L)//2:][::-1]) if el1==el2]
```

There is a lot going on, so let me explain step by step:

- `L[:len(L)//2+1]` is the first half of the list plus an extra element (which is useful for lists of odd lengths)
- `L[len(L)//2:][::-1]` is the second half of the list, reversed (`[::-1]`)
- [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) creates a list of pairs from two lists. it stops at the end of the shortest list. We use this in the case the length of the list is even, so the extra term in the first half is neglected
- [List comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) essentially equivalent to a for loop, but useful to create a list "on the fly". It will return an element only if the if condition is true, otherwise it will pass.

You can easily modify the solution above if you are interested in the *indexes* (of the first half) where the match occurs:

```
[idx for idx, (el1, el2) in enumerate(zip(L[:len(L)//2+1], L[len(L)//2:][::-1])) if el1==el2]
```